# The new AJAX tag editing works for locked questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits

I could add a tag for this question, although it is locked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762825/what-programming-techy-name-should-i-give-my-new-pup

The direct edit link [isn't functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762825/edit), so I assume it's a bug.

Comment: Nice find. Now how can I exploit this while it still works? :P

Comment: You can bump them all one last time.

Comment: It's quite a useful loophole - you can retag migrated questions to remove the "belongs-on-..." tag.

Comment: @ChrisF: Now I'm *really* hoping this gets a `[status-bydesign]`.

Comment: How do I use this to unlock my questions?

Comment: @Evan, you can't use this to unlock your questions.

Comment: Dang. Wish I had 10k on SO... I could have made a big dent in `[not-programming-related]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, we had to fix this - tag editing is only allowed on locked questions by moderators.

Good find, though!

Comment: This fix will be pushed tonight.

Comment: Damn - let's hope that the "belongs-on-" tags remain at 0 on Stack Overflow and Super User.