# When a question is locked, the "edit" link is inactive. I think that the "edit tag" link should be inactive, too

Tags: bug, tags, edits, locked-questions, inline-tag-editor

When a question is locked, the "edit" link is inactive. I think that the "edit tag" link should be inactive, too.

From what I have tried on math.SE, it seems that when a question is locked, you can click on "edit tags" but when you try to save your edits, you get an error saying: This question cannot be edited at this time.

I was not able to see the same behavior here on meta.SO, probably because I do not have sufficient rep to edit posts.

You can see an example in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12474/why-this-question-cannot-be-edited)
on meta.math.SE. (I will post also some screenshots here.)

I have tried several locked questions on math.SE, the behavior is the same. For example
[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281089/proof-of-the-iff-statement-of-lower-semicontinuous-under-closed-sets-but-i-have),
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286462/on-normal-subgroup-of-a-finite-group),
[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298063/show-if-the-elements-of-b-are-integral-and-delta-bk-is-square-free-the),
[4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537481/continuity-of-functions-between-metric-spaces).

I tried to find out whether this has already been reported here, I
only found this question:
[The new AJAX tag editing works for locked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48689/the-new-ajax-tag-editing-works-for-locked-questions).
It is not exactly the same and it is marked as
[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

---

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot: tag edit]

[image: Screenshot: edit is inactive]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Indeed, inline tag editing is 10K privilege

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The new AJAX tag editing works for locked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48689/the-new-ajax-tag-editing-works-for-locked-questions)